# css make position one paragraph to top and another to button

Tags: html, css, sass, less

this is my current code:

```
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="date">
            <p class="date-top">23/4/5/66</p>

            <p class="dote-bottom">23/4/5/66</p>
        </div>
       
        <div class="text">
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.date {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.text {
    float: right;
}
```

this is my screenshot [image]

I am now struggling to position the one date to the top and another should be bottum

[image]

can anyone help me to achieve this? I am stuck here to acheive this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use floats, use up to date CSS to get the desired behaviour. Nowadays [you can use flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve something like this.

```css
.col-md-3 {
display: flex
}

.date {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 
 margin-right: 10px; /* just to have some space, you can also use flexbox to space your .date and .text divs. */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="date">
    <p class="date-top">23/4/5/66</p>

    <p class="dote-bottom">23/4/5/66</p>
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is best approach using flex layout. Upvoting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```css
.date {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.text {
    float: right;
}
.date-top {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
.date-bottom {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="date">
            <p class="date-top">23/4/5/66</p>

            <p class="date-bottom">23/4/5/66</p>
        </div>
       
        <div class="text">
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if need fixed position then will works. Another approach so upvoting.

Comment: Sorry, no, your solution is wrong, coz, it is fixed